# How I will compare Two flat files in ssis?

Tags: file, ssis, compare, flat

TableOne.txt (txt file)

```
LoadNumber  Name    Address
101         Yogesh  ABC
102         Zebra   XYZ
103         Kattle  BTM
```

TableTwo.txt (txt file)

```
LoadNumber  Cost    EName
101         240     Yogesh
105         500     Kavita
110         340     Kamal
```

Now I want to compare these flat files.
1. I want to all data which is not present in table two text file base is LoadNumber and also I want all data which is not present in table one text files base is LoadNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- read both text files through a **Flat File Source** component

2- **Sort** them by LoadNumber

3- connect to a **Merge Join** compnonent (join type: full outer join) and join by TableOne.LoadNumber - TableTwo.LoadNumber

4- **Conditional Split** based on ISNULL(tableXXXX.LoadNumber), e.g. if null for TableOne.LoadNumber then is missing from table1

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i am not getting whole data...means LoadNumber,Name,Cost,Address...I am getting only LoadNumber

Comment: You need to make sure the non key fields are passed through the sort (i.e. pass through checked) and also from the merge join (all field  from both tables in the merge checked)

Comment: thanks i got it....but one more problem..can i make one data set for both record..??

Comment: you can add a Union All after the Conditional Split, you will have the 6 columns (3 per table) in one row

Comment: i used...ISNULL([One.LoadNumber]) || ISNULL([Two.LoadNumber]) this condition.....now i am getting proper data....can i use this..or not

Comment: yes, you can although I would separated it into two outputs from the conditional split, see the picture I uploaded; and please upvote if this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

you can do that a C# script in a SSIS script task.
Ref: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/File-Stream/Comparetwofiles.htm

```
using System; 
using System.IO;  

public class CompFiles {  
  public static void Main(string[] args) {  
    int i=0, j=0;  
    FileStream f1;  
    FileStream f2;  

    try {  
      // open first file 
      try {  
        f1 = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open);  
      } catch(FileNotFoundException exc) {  
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);  
        return;  
      }  

      // open second file  
      try {  
        f2 = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.Open);  
      } catch(FileNotFoundException exc) {  
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);  
        return;  
      }  
    } catch(IndexOutOfRangeException exc) {  
      Console.WriteLine(exc.Message + "\nUsage: CompFile f1 f2");  
      return;  
    }  

    // Compare files  
    try {  
      do {  
        i = f1.ReadByte();  
        j = f2.ReadByte();  
        if(i != j) break; 
      } while(i != -1 && j != -1);  
    } catch(IOException exc) {  
      Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);  
    }  
    if(i != j)  
      Console.WriteLine("Files differ."); 
    else 
      Console.WriteLine("Files are the same."); 

    f1.Close();  
    f2.Close();  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be to load both flat files into SQL tables ins Flat File Source & use Execute SQL tasks to JOIN the tables & get the data.

Makes the SSIS workflow a bit simpler but obviously requires 2 SQL tables.

Don't forget to clear the tables at the start if you use this method.